# How to make ASP .net Webservice function parameter non mandatory

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have this function in the webservice.

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void getbalance(string login, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            //some code
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //show error message
        }
    }
```

Now I want to add a new parameter namely date to this. But since this `webservice` is being used for an android app adding a new parameter would make this function redundant. I know the obvious solution is to make another function but is there another way through which I can add a new parameter and if the query string through which this function is called doesn't have the date parameter, instead of giving an error it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nullable optional parameters are the way to go:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void getbalance(string login, string password, DateTime? date = null)
{
    try
    {
        //some code

        if(date.HasValue)
        {
            // Do something with date. You can get the date using date.Value
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //show error message
    }
}
```

If you pass a date in, then date will have a value. Otherwise, date will be null.

Though, IMO, you should consider a different design :)